# Стоит ли задавать вопрос, если знаешь на него ответ

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы, самоответы

Одной из причин времяпровождения на SO его участники могут назвать пополнение базы данных вопросов и ответов (не будем говорить об том, что разделение SO на "регионы" (ruSO, enSO, …) является, по моему мнению, ошибкой).

Так вот, если ты знаешь ответ на вопрос и считаешь этот вопрос полезным/информативным/стоящим, можно ли его задать, а затем дать на него ответ? На сколько это целесообразно? Ведь через время об этом вопросе можно и забыть – неплохо было бы его где-то <s>(даже не знаю где)</s> задокументировать.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос уже дан
[в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> ## Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?
>
> Совершенно точно стоит!  Мы призываем всех участников отвечать на
> свои вопросы:
>
> - если у вас есть вопрос, на который вы заранее знаете ответ;
> - если вы хотите поделиться своими знаниями с сообществом, то есть чтобы ваши коллеги, да и вы сами, в будущем при возникновении аналогичной, либо схожей проблемы смогли быстро найти решение;
>
> опубликуйте вопрос c вашим ответом к нему!
>
> […]

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, что да. Этот вопрос может быть кому-то полезен, <s>да и можно фармить в 2 раза больше репы</s>.

Думаю, что будет мнение типа: «Зачем? Если вопрос не задали, значит ответ на него никому не нужен». Тогда почему на хороших/сложных/интересных/<s>простых</s> вопросах набираются голоса? Хоть 1 голос «за» значит, что этот вопрос хоть кому-то, да был нужен (думаю очевидно, что голосов «за» будет не 1).

Лучше задокументировать вопрос/ответ сегодня, чем забыть его завтра.

Comment: `да и можно фармить в 2 раза больше репы` ;)